# How to customize the omniauth identity for api call returns json status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to  call the the rest api for sign in and sign up for omniauth identity aunthetication which takes standard url for post call auth/idenitity/callback and auth/idenitity/register .

I want to call the sign in and sign up api url for api like

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/identity/callback
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/identity/register
```

created the controller

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create

     // logic given in standard documentaion of omnuaith identity gem 

    end
end
```

and set the routes like

```
namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do 
   end
end
```

How I  can customize my routes  or path so the post api call will be successfully call. by default we have create method in sessions controller  to autheticate. "auth/identity/callback" url return auth hash. I want ot customize the the code for api call like api/vi/auth/identity/callback.

I tried `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/identity/callback` by calling postman but return error

```
NoMethodError at /api/v1/auth/identity/callback

===============================================

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

routes to call api post

api_v1_failure GET      /api/v1/auth/failure(.:format)                      api/v1/sessions#failure
                             api_v1 GET|POST /api/v1/auth/:provider/callback(.:format)           api/v1/sessions#create

/api/v1/auth/:provider/callback is the post call of omniauth idenitity for sign in I want to customize it

Comment: where do you use `[]` ? also your routes are incomplete... please include the output from `rake routes`

Comment: [ ] contain the auth_hash ..will use to authenticate the identity using email and other params

Comment: ok nice .. i asked to see `rake routes`